# Header never prints using jquery.floatThead

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, printing

I am trying to fix a fixed header until Navbar where the user can view the table and print the same.
So I tried using **jquery.floatThead.js** which works perfectly w.r.t my requirement in the HTML view window, but when we try to print using this jquery.floatThead, the header is never printed. Where could I going wrong ? or is it an issue with the jquery.floatThead.js script ?

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ja8xhn63/1/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table').floatThead();
  });

  var myApp = new function() {
    this.printTable = function() {
      var tab = document.getElementById('tabledetails');
      var style = "<style>";
      style = style + "table {width: 100%;font: 17px Calibri;}";
      style = style + "table, th, td {border: solid 1px #DDD; border-collapse: collapse;";
      style = style + "padding: 2px 3px;text-align: center;}";
      style = style + "table, th {color: black}";
      style = style + "</style>";

      var win = window.open('', '', 'height=700,width=700');
      win.document.write(style); //  add the style.
      win.document.write(tab.outerHTML);
      win.document.close();
      win.print();
    }
  }
```

```css
h1 {
  background: lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
  font: 28px Georgia, Serif;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

/*.tableFixHead { overflow-y: auto; height: 600px; }*/

#tabledetails td {
  border: solid 0.5px black;
  font-size: 9px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 500;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#tabledetails th {
  border: solid 0.5px white;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  background-color: #0080ff;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.mytable {
  top: 60px;
}

@media print {
  footer {
    page-break-after: always;
  }

  table {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  }

  div.viewfile {
    display: none;
  }

  table,
  th,
  td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 2px 3px;
  }

  .myTable th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
  }

  .myTable thead th {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  #tabledetails td {
    border: solid 0.5px black;
    font-size: 9px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 500;
  }

  #tabledetails th {
    border: solid 0.5px white;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 500;
  }

  .tableFixHead th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
  }

  .myTable.floatThead-table {
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: solid 0.5px white;
  }

  td.hidetd {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: You print everything inside `tabledetails` but your header is not a part of this. try with `document.getElementById('printreport');`

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen I mean to say Table Header which is still not printed even after I use document.getElementById('printreport');

Comment: This issue has been solved. More details on : https://github.com/mkoryak/floatThead/issues/466